# Метод Socket Send(byte[] buffer) в режиме TCP долго не бросает исключения

Tags: c#, сокет

"Не баг а фича". Есть устройство на которое я отправляю команды со скоростью 16 шт./сек. Данный метод Socket `AcceptedClient.Send(byte[] buffer)` помещен в блок `try/catch`. В блоке `catch` я ставлю флаг на устройство `deviceLost = true`, а далее пробую переподключиться. В случае неудачи удаляю устройство из списка устройств. Но, при отключении устройства "из розетки", `AcceptedClient.Send(byte[] buffer)` продолжает слать на него команды как ни в чем не бывало еще секунд 10-15. И до этого времени программа в блок `catch` не заходит и устройство висит в списке. Когда я включаю устройство снова, оно "подхватывается", и "стрим" команд на него продолжается. Как можно сделать чтобы `AcceptedClient.Send(byte[] buffer)` выбивал исключение раньше?

Comment: @Alex F Понял, спасибо. А таймаут на получение "disconnect" я никак контролировать не могу? Просто в том режиме подключения устройства в котором я работаю оно не отправляет подтверждения выполнения комманд.

Comment: @Alex F Это динамическое освещение для лампочки. Там потеря данных не страшна. Просто при выкл/вкл выключателя лампочка включает нормальное освещение. Я хотел ее так выводить из списка для AmbientLight не подходя к компу, чтобы свет в комнате нормальный включить и оставить только ту что за монитором(у меня их две), Но она опять динамичить продолжает)) Приходится выжидать по 10-15 сек) Оригинальная програма на андроид для этой лампочки тоже перебить AmbientLight не может) Придется тогда и на телефон свою писать, или для веба.

Comment: @Alex F ок, спасибо, погуглю.